# I've deleted all the files in my directory. How can I get them back?

Tags: perforce

I'm new to Perforce and, to be honest, I'm hating it.
I had about 20 files in my c:\workspaces\perforce directory and I selected all of them and hit the delete key.
They were all checked in before I deleted them.
I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to get them back (Perforce is sooooo unintuitive) but there's nothing that stands out to a n00b like me to.
How can I get the latest revisions back into the directory from Perforce?

Answer (score 30):

You need to do a force sync.

On the command line:

```
$> p4 sync -f
```

In the P4V GUI:

1. Right-click on the directory to update
2. Select 'Get Revision'
3. In the dialog, check 'Force operation'
4. Click 'Get Revision'

Answer (score 13):

The perforce server keeps track of which files you pulled in last time. This is done so that, the next `sync` only brings in the files which have changes since the last sync, instead of all the files once again.

To override this behavior, you need to use the `-f` option.

> The -f flag forces resynchronization even if the client already has
>   the file, and overwriting any writable files. This flag doesn't
>   affect open files.

If you're using the command line client, you can run this command from the directory where you want to sync up:

```
p4 sync -f ...
```

You might also want to check the list of `opened` files, since `sync -f` will not be bringing in changes corresponding to those files (even if you have deleted them).

This command should list all the opened files:

```
p4 opened ...
```

If you have any files listed in the above list, which you had deleted as well, you should revert them before running `sync -f`.

```
p4 revert <FILE1> <FILE2>
p4 sync -f ...
```

If you're using `p4v`, you could follow the steps mentioned by [dwinkle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253433/dwikle):

```
1. Right click the folder in your workspace
2. Choose `Get Revision` in the context menu.
3. Choose `Get Latest revision`
4. Check `Force Operation (replace file even if you already have the revision specified)
5. Click on `Get Revision` button to fetch the files.
```

To look at the list of opened files using `p4v`, you would have to look at your list of pending changelists. You should be looking in the `default` changelist, if you have not put the files in any speficic changelist. Right click on files that you see there that you had deleted earlier, and choose `Revert`.

Answer (score 6):

if you have files checked out, and then deleted. You need to revert(p4 revert -a //...) the folder before you get latest forced (p4 sync -f).

Comment: Revert won't have anything to do until the missing files are opened for delete.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative:

`p4 reconcile`
`p4 revert //...`

Comment: The GUI version of this was the best solution for me. I right-clicked the parent version and reconciled the deletes to a scratch changelist, then reverted that changelist.

Comment: I consider this preferable to `sync -f` because the entire workspace may contain many, many more files than just the ones accidentally deleted and a force sync will copy even files that are already present. Scanning a large workspace for changes may be slow, but it's faster than re-downloading everything.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the old client, one solution would be to pull down a new client:

```
p4 newclient
p4 sync
```

If you want the client to have the same name, you can do a forced sync as others have mentioned:

```
p4 sync -f
```

If you want the client to have the same name, but your directory is no longer recognized as a p4 workspace, you will need to delete the client and then recreate it.

```
p4 -c <client_name> client -d <client_name>
p4 newclient
```

Comment: `p4 sync -f` is what I needed :) p4 reconcile seems useless.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on parent directory.
2. Click "Reconcile" in context menu.

   - Let a new change list be created.
3. Right click changelist.
4. Revert change.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried everything and I couldn't get all of my files to revert, so I tried deleting them and then I couldn't get all of them back. I restarted my pc, and tried numerous solutions found online. In the end my problem was solved by one or all of the following: upgrading to the latest P4V application, running the application with elevated permissions, and going to lunch after forcing get latest.

If you wasted half of a day. You may want to try the above.

Answer (score 0):

> I've deleted all the files in my directory. How can I get them back?

One wrinkle to this that I just stumbled over is that if you remove the *directory* you can't just use `p4 sync -f` to get it back.  I wanted a complete clean version of the directory so I did a:

```
rm -rf directory1
```

However when I did a `p4 sync -f directory1` on it, it spits out:

```
directory1 - no such file(s).
```

What I found that works is to recover a *file* inside of the directory first:

```
p4 sync -f directory1/some-file
```

You will have to know the name of one of the files inside of the missing directory which you can get using:

```
p4 files //depot/some/path/directory1/\*
```

Once you get one of the filenames, do:

```
p4 sync -f directory1/some-file
```

This should create the `directory1` directory.  Then you can do a full sync inside of the created directory:

```
cd directory1
p4 sync -f ...
```

Hope this helps someone else.