# Deleted (not submitted) directory in Perforce: cannot revert, force-sync, reconcile or do anything else

Tags: perforce

I have deleted a directory in a 3rd-party Perforce client. It should have used `p4 delete`, but I cannot be sure. It was not submitted.

Now:

- I don't see the deleted directory in p4v.
- `p4 revert` fails:

  ```
  p4 revert //depot/path/deleted-directory/...
  //depot/path/deleted-directory/... - file(s) not opened on this client.
  ```
- I cannot force-sync `deleted-directory` to revert the deletion:

  ```
  p4 sync -f //depot/path/deleted-directory
  //depot/path/deleted-directory no such file(s).

  p4 sync -f //depot/path/deleted-directory/...
  //depot/path/deleted-directory/file1.txt#2 - deleted as /Users/me/depot/path/deleted-directory/file1.txt
  ```
- I cannot reconcile them:

  ```
  p4 reconcile //depot/path/deleted-directory/...
  //depot/path/deleted-directory/... - no file(s) to reconcile.
  ```
- `p4 opened` doesn't see them:

  ```
  p4 opened
  File(s) not opened on this client.
  ```

How do I get this deleted directory into a changelist or at least revert it?

I tried all suggestions from "[I've deleted all the files in my directory. How can I get them back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552066/ive-deleted-all-the-files-in-my-directory-how-can-i-get-them-back)" except for checking out a new workspace, which I will eventually do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
p4 undo //depot/path/deleted-directory/...#head
p4 submit
```

That will undo the head revisions in that directory (i.e. the deletion) by creating new revisions that are copied from the prior ones.

**Longer answer to explain why all the things you tried didn't work:**

`p4 opened` and `p4 revert` both operate on files that are currently *open*.  If you hadn't yet submitted, then `revert` would put the files back, but since this deletion was already submitted, there were no open files to revert.

When you force-synced you were just forcing a re-sync to the head revision, which is deleted (just like the files in your workspace), so no matter how hard you force the sync all you're going to get is a lot of nothing.  If you had done:

```
p4 sync "//depot/path/deleted-directory/...#<head"
```

in order to sync to the revision prior to `#head`, that would have done the trick.  Note that no `-f` flag is necessary.  Once the files were synced to the correct revision, you would also be able to undo the delete by following that sync command with:

```
p4 add //depot/path/deleted-directory/...
p4 submit
```

Similarly, `reconcile` didn't do anything because the files are deleted at the head revision and deleted in your workspace, so there's nothing to reconcile.  If you wanted to get really weird with it you could undo the delete via `reconcile` by using a combination of `sync` and `flush` to simulate the condition of having re-added new copies of the files:

```
p4 sync "//depot/path/deleted-directory/...#<head"
p4 flush //depot/path/deleted-directory/...
p4 reconcile //depot/path/deleted-directory/...
```

In addition to being unnecessarily complex, this `reconcile`-based solution will lose the information of which revision the re-added files came from (thanks to the `p4 flush`), so I would not recommend it.  Go with `undo` and if you're on an old server version that doesn't support that do the normal `sync`/`add` thing.

Comment: Thank you very much. There's a problem: this deleted directory is not submitted. Sorry for being unclear. All the changes are local. There is no revision in the repo with the deletion.

Comment: Everything you've described is consistent with a submitted deletion.  Maybe include the output of `p4 files //depot/path/deleted-directory/...`?

Comment: Yay! Listing the files found the CL number! I got a list of `//depot/path/deleted-directory/file1.txt - delete change 25445 (text)`. It's a very old CL and the `deleted-directory` had been long deleted in the depot and only survived locally. Strangely, it wasn't deleted during syncs or wasn't shown as added in my clients.

Comment: So your answer is correct when it says that the deletion was submitted. One thing I would add to it is this test with `p4 files`.

Comment: So really nothing ever got deleted because none of your files had ever been added...?  

Comment: No, the directory was there, then it was deleted by another user. But for some reason it was not deleted from my workspace during previous syncs. I need to run force-sync on weekends, I think.

Comment: A normal sync will generally suffice.  It doesn't sound like anything was wrong at all -- the directory was deleted on the server, and you didn't have anything in your workspace.  You were already perfectly in sync, and the only thing that was wrong was that you didn't realize that you were already synced and you were second-guessing yourself.  :)

Comment: Hardly. I made a search for a string in my editor, and files in the deleted directory had a lot of hits. I had the search results open when I wrote the question. The directory was still on the disk.

Comment: In that case `reconcile` would have added them.  Maybe they're also excluded from your client view?  Or maybe there's some kind of path confusion and/or typo at play (maybe a difference in case, if this is on a Unix server)?

Comment: I ran `p4 client -o`, the clientspec includes the whole grandparent directory. Probably I made a typo.